# Allow unknown methods on object

Tags: typescript, .d.ts

I have an object which has multiple method names which are not known on compile time. However, the signature of the method is always the same. I tried to use an index type like this:

```
interface List<T> extends Array<T> {
    [key: string]: (...arg0: any[]) => List<T>
    [key: string]: () => List<any>
    each(fn: Function): void
    each(...args: any[]): void
    toArray(): T[]
}
```

However, typescript complains that it cannot fit the other method signatures into this:

> Property 'each' of type '{ (fn: Function): void; (...args: any[]): void; }' is not assignable to string index type '(...arg0: any[]) => List'.

I know its an unusual thing, but how can you do what I need in typescript?

Answer (score 0):

```
interface List<T>{
[key: string] : ((...arg) => any) | (() => List<any>);
each: ((fn: Function) => void) | ((...args: any[]) => void);
toArray : () => T[];
```

}

is this what you want?

Comment: Is there a reason you merge all this declarations?

Comment: yes you are defining same property in same interface twice so merging it where you can mention multiple types of same property

Comment: Yes having overloads is pretty common in typescript. Merging declaration just makes it harder to read